# Trying to create a page to read a CSV file into a DataTable then insert to SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, csv, datatable

I have been trying to figure out why this code is not working. I am not as familiar with reading `CSV` files as i would like to be.

I have been trying different things and have assembled this code, which at least the reader was working, but now I am getting no results when I run this and I am not sure where I am going wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
'delete existing tables data
SQL = "delete [tblRPTstoreclasses]"

cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()

Dim thedatatable As New DataTable

With thedatatable
    .Columns.Add("storeid", System.Type.GetType("system.string"))
    .Columns.Add("group", System.Type.GetType("system.string"))
    .Columns.Add("levelnumber", System.Type.GetType("system.string"))
End With

Dim newrow As DataRow = thedatatable.NewRow
Dim MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Todds-Reports\UPLOADS\" & filenamestring)

MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}

Dim currentRow As String()

While Not MyReader.EndOfData
    Try
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        For Each currentField As String In currentRow
            If cnt = 0 Then
                Response.Write(currentField)
                newrow("storeid") = currentField
                cnt = cnt + 1
            ElseIf cnt = 1 Then
                Response.Write(currentField)
                newrow("group") = currentField
                cnt = cnt + 1
            ElseIf cnt = 2 Then
                Response.Write(currentField)
                newrow("levelnumber") = currentField
                cnt = 0
            End If
        Next
        MyReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
    End Try
End While


Dim sortOrder As String = "group ASC"
Dim result As DataRow() = thedatatable.Select("levelnumber = 2", sortOrder)
group = ""

For Each row As DataRow In result
    If group <> "" Then
        If group = row(1) Then
            stores = stores & "," & row(0)
        Else
            SQL = "insert into [tblRPTstoreclasses] (storeid,levelnumber) values ('" & stores & "','2')"
            Response.Write("SQL=" & SQL)
            cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

            group = row(1)
            stores = stores & row(0)
        End If

    Else
        group = row(1)
        stores = stores & row(0)
    End If
Next

SQL = "insert into [tblRPTstoreclasses] (storeid,levelnumber) values ('" & stores & "','2')"
Response.Write("SQL=" & SQL)
cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()

result = thedatatable.Select("levelnumber = 4", sortOrder)
group = ""

For Each row As DataRow In result
    If group <> "" Then
        If group = row(1) Then
            stores = stores & "," & row(0)
        Else
            SQL = "insert into [tblRPTstoreclasses] (storeid,levelnumber) values ('" & stores & "','4')"
            Response.Write("SQL=" & SQL)
            cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

            group = row(1)
            stores = stores & row(0)
        End If
    Else
        group = row(1)
        stores = stores & row(0)
    End If
Next

SQL = "insert into [tblRPTstoreclasses] (storeid,levelnumber) values ('" & stores & "','4')"
Response.Write("SQL=" & SQL)
cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()

result = thedatatable.Select("levelnumber = 6", sortOrder)
group = ""

For Each row As DataRow In result
    If group <> "" Then
        If group = row(1) Then
            stores = stores & "," & row(0)
        Else
            SQL = "insert into [tblRPTstoreclasses] (storeid,levelnumber) values ('" & stores & "','6')"
            Response.Write("SQL=" & SQL)
            cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()

            group = row(1)
            stores = stores & row(0)
        End If
    Else
        group = row(1)
        stores = stores & row(0)
    End If
Next

SQL = "insert into [tblRPTstoreclasses] (storeid,levelnumber) values ('" & stores & "','6')"
Response.Write("SQL=" & SQL)
cmd = New SqlCommand(SQL, conn)
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: Run it in debug mode and step through each line - see if its an issue with reading from the file or saving the data

Comment: thanks wasn't thinking about that. Have done so and am finding the reader is only reading the first line of the CSV and then jumping out of the loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show a small example of how your data is setup in the csv file? Like the first 5 lines

Comment: example of data    4,A,2
16,A,2
9,B,2
7,B,2
19,B,2
23,C,2

Comment: You're calling `MyReader.Close()` inside the loop.  Do you really want to close the file after reading each record? I think not. You should be creating the `TextFieldParser` with a `Using` statement and then the file will be closed implicitly at the right time.